python-vlc sound is cut before the end on some files but not others
I have a script that plays mp3s that I generate with azure ai speeech.
The first file, intro.mp3 is the direct output. The file ends 1 sec/half a seconde before when I play it with python-vlc, but no problem with windows media player ou VLC on windows
The 2nd file intro4.mp3 (I just resaved the same one with Sony Soundforge) and this one works well...
I can't go file by file doing that, so I tried with ffmpeg, but the ffmpeg file has the same issue as the first one... intro3.mp3
Used the code
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", f"{dir_path}/music/{song['folder']}/{song['song']}/intro.mp3", "-vn", "-ar", "44100", "-ac", "2", "-b:a", "192k", f"{dir_path}/music/{song['folder']}/{song['song']}/intro3.mp3"])
I am on windows, here is the script I use to read the files
import vlc
from vlc import Instance

introvoice1 = THE FILE
voiceover = vlc.Instance()
voiceover_player = voiceover.media_player_new()
voiceover_player.audio_set_volume(120)
voiceover_player.set_media(voiceover.media_new(introvoice1))
voiceover_player.play()

It's been a few days and I reallly don't get what I am doing wrong... Or what is wrong with the file
I am ok with converting the file but that did not work with ffmpeg. Even tryed to convert first to wav (which is not played by VLC... or python vlc) then to mp3
Sometimes it seems also the beginning is cut...
Tried to convert, to change format
One thing seemed to work was to ffmpeg convert to wav then to mp3 again and changing from 44100 to 48000... but same conversion from mp3 to mp3 do not work
playsound seems to read it ok, but I need to be able to play different sounds together with different volumes...
